# PHP Grabbing Dynamically Generated "Select name"

Tags: php, pdo

Using PDO :

Hello, I've created a scheduling system that uses dynamically created "selection names". That look like this :

```
echo "<p>12am : <select name=\"".$schedule[26]['schid']."\">";
```

I'm a barbarian when it comes to php and my method of doing this is my own.
What I can't figure out is how to get the value of the selection name for the INSERT query.

I don't really want to have someone rewrite my code, I simply need to understand how to take the dynamically generated selection variable and put in the format that will work with an Insert statement.

So there's 24 selections for 24 hours a day, each selection has

```
$options .= "<option value=\"$userid\">$djname</option>";
```

which populate the options.

All of that works, I get the hourly schedule ID's and the options populate the drop down. The option is easy to understand because it is just the one variable,
but for the life of me I can not see how to grab  the actual select name variable.

I'm not looking for ideas on how to do a scheduling system or how it could be improved, this is a project for college, so all I'm asking is how to grab the dynamically generated select name from

```
echo "<p>12am : <select name=\"".$schedule[26]['schid']."\">";
```

Thank you

(I've searched the forums for about 12 hours today, everything was about "option values")

Comment: Assuming you POST the form, the names will be the keys of your `$_POST` array.

Comment: So doing  $_POST['$schedule'] =>$row['schid']; What is tripping me up is this :  <select name ="4">  The 4 is dynamically generated.... so the name is never the same .

Comment: Slowly syncing in... :) I see when I hit my submit button it creates a "id&id" pair. Need some sleep, maybe the answer will come in a dream. :). The first id is the userid and second is the schedule id.

Comment: still not getting it, and not getting the UPDATE to catch the variables.